# Unable to process entire dataset in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a dataset of around 2100 files of the same format, and I am scraping some data from them. I ran  the following code to take the resulting dictionary that comes from the scanfile function and writes it into a csv file

```
def createtable():
    x = os.listdir('./dataset')

    with open('data.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['name', 'Error', 'val1', 'val2']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for i in range(1400, 1500):
            writer.writerow(scanFile(x[i]))
```

When I do this for a range less than 300, I create the csv file I want successfully, but when I try to do the entire thing, I get this error...

```
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte
```

How do I fix this issue? I really do not know how to even start fixing it as it works for small test cases but then fails at a larger scale.

Comment: this is not  an issue with the number of files but an issue with data in one of your files, likely one around the 300 mark if thats where the error starts. You should print the file name during processing and see what the last file was before the error and then debug the data in that file.

Comment: This occurs when the writer runs into a non-utf-8 character. You could either go in and find what the character is (it tells you the position where to look) and change it, or try using a writer which supports other character encoding beyond utf-8. Pandas supports other encoding if you want to look into that.

Comment: If you want to determine the encoding for the files in the directory, you can do ```file *``` while in the directory. It looks like your code expects UTF-8 but receives a non-UTF-8 character. The output of the file command will tell you which file is not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you done any research? This has been asked on here before, no?